# add bootstrap classes to rails 5 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style the following form with bootstrap:

```
<%= form_tag("/products", method: "get") do %>
   <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:", ) %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

this code is being rendered like this:

```
<form action="/products" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <label for="q">Search for:</label>
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" data-disable-with="Search" />
</form>
```

I would like to add classes to the tags `form` and `input`.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag("/products", method: "get", class: "someClass") do %>
   <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:", ) %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: 'anyclass') %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

just replace `someClass` and `anyclass` with your choice

Comment: you are welcome. You can accept and upvote if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<%= form_tag("/products", method: "get", class: 'attributes-goes-here') do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:", ) %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: 'attributes-goes-here') %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Note the ', class: 'attributes-goes-here'

Comment: `text_field_tag(:q, class: 'attributes-goes-here')` will not work. `text_field_tag` takes input field's `value` in second argument and HTML options in last or third argument

Comment: Thank you very much jhack this was helpfull, only problem was that the nil was missing after :q, but it was helpfull nonetheless. thank you for your time